# Responsive break point is not working for Slick slideshow

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive, slick.js

My slick slider's responsive breakpoints are not working. I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing helped me. Maybe I have a problem with HTML structure or something.

This is my demo - https://jsfiddle.net/eax5tu4s/

```
$(".slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    responsive:[
      {
        breakpoint: 1200,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by removing the `variableWidth: true` setting, since it allows each slide to grow with its contents.

```js
$(".slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive:[
      {
        breakpoint: 1200,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
    ]
  });
```

I also added the Slick CSS files to your JSFiddle to make this work. I reduced the breakpoint in order to test it in the smaller window of the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ga6w1zmo/

Answer (score 2):

+1 [@Ed Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287476/ed-lucas) for pointing the variable width issue. Bang on!

Also worth noting with slicks responsive breakpoints, by default is desktop first. So your `1200` breakpoint settings is everything below `1200` window width, which is kinda backwards if you are building with a framework which is mobile first.

You can flip this using slicks [`mobileFirst`](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) option set to `true` (default `false`) to reverse the breakpoints.

For example you could define your frameworks breakpoints as an object...

```
const breakpoint = {
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200
};
```

Then define `mobileFirst: true` in your slick options and configure your slick options mobile first to desktop...

```
$('.slider').slick({
  mobileFirst: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: breakpoint.md,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xl,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

So each slick breakpoint setting is everything up rather than down, and your initial slick options are mobile first